# How to dynamically create footnote with itext?

Tags: itext, footnotes

I need to transform an XML file to a PDF. I choose iText and XML Worker to process this.

The xml contains tags that I would like to use as footnotes in the final document. I read about the PdfPageEventHelper that I'm already using to set a header and footer but this does not fit with the footnotes, considering the content is dynamic(variable list of footnotes, if any).

I can't fix the page margin for all the pages: some pages will have no footnote and I don't want to maintain a big white space at the bottom of each page.

Is there a way to tell iText to delay the processing of a specific tag or ask it to render it in a different table/cell/... of the document?

Any help/idea would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no high-level mechanism in iText for creating footnotes yet (as of version 5.5.8).

Most likely the situation in this regard still is as it was in 2008 when @BrunoLowagie wrote [this answer](https://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg36348.html) on the iText support mailing list:

> ### Re: [iText-questions] Footnote
>
> Bruno Lowagie Fri, 22 Feb 2008 10:49:20 -0800
>
> Markos Fragkakis wrote:
>
> > Markos Fragkakis wrote:
> >
> > > Hi all,
> > >
> > > I need to create footnotes over certain words in the same page. Is there 
> > >       a way to do this?
> > >
> > > Markos
> >
> > Do I need to use a superscript to draw the 1 over my word, and then use 
> >     the onEndPage event to do the rest? Is there a more elegant solution?
>
> There's no built-in mechanism to provide footnotes.
>
> Your suggested approach comes close, but you may experience
>   the problem that there's no sufficient space at the bottom
>   of the page to display the footnotes. I fear the even less
>   elegant solution where you would work with 2 ColumnText objects,
>   one for the content and one for the footnotes will be the only
>   solution: you keep track of the necessary height for the footnotes
>   with the latter column and add content to the former column as
>   long as the sum of the heights of the two columns fits the page.
>
> best regards,
>
> Bruno

Thus it looks like you have to switch to this mid-level mechanism, creating two `ColumnText` instances, one for regular content of the current page, one for footnotes there.

---

One might wonder why there is no high-level footnote mechanism in iText. Considering how few hits I found, though, google'ing for iText & footnotes, there simply seem to be hardly any requests for this feature, at least in the open web.

---

If endnotes are an alternative option for you, they should be much easier to implement, in particular you can do so using high level methods.

> **Footnotes** are notes at the foot of the page while **endnotes** are collected under a separate heading at the end of a chapter, volume, or entire work. Unlike footnotes, endnotes have the advantage of not affecting the layout of the main text, but may cause inconvenience to readers who have to move back and forth between the main text and the endnotes.
>
> *([Note (typography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(typography)) in Wikipedia)*

Here you merely have to collect the notes in some list, and when you get to the end of a chapter/volume/work, you add a heading and then all the notes as normal content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Indeed, I'm surprised there no discussion or how-to about what I do consider as a basic element of a document.
Can you please explain what you mean by endnotes and how you would implement this? Thanks

Comment: ***Footnotes** are notes at the foot of the page while **endnotes** are collected under a separate heading at the end of a chapter, volume, or entire work. Unlike footnotes, endnotes have the advantage of not affecting the layout of the main text, but may cause inconvenience to readers who have to move back and forth between the main text and the endnotes*, cf. [Note (typography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(typography)) in Wikipedia.

Comment: That would be straight forward to implement indeed, but it does not fit my needs. Thanks for your help anyway